# How to replicate an anchor tag in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, csv, microsoft-excel-2003

I have an Excel (csv) like this:

```
column1  link
yahoo    <a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> 
google   <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Is there any way to make link column behave like a normal anchor tag, such that it shows like:

```
column1  link
yahoo    Yahoo (clicking it should redirect) 
google   Google
```

I can use macros or any tips while exporting this in csv.

Comment: What have you tried already? You could record a macro creating a link and use that code to format your data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as a csv file.  You would have to convert it to a proper Excel file - a `.xls` or `.xlsx` file to display hyperlinks as text.